# problem with graphics.h in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, bgi, scanline

i am writing a simple program actually implementing scan line algorithm in C++ using Visual Studio 2010. but i am getting an error saying graphics.h file can not be found. can anybody tell me how to solve that problem? or any other way(without using graphics.h) to implement scan line algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably `#include <windows.h>`. It's not entirely clear what you mean by "scan line algorithm", but at first blush it sounds a bit like [`LineDDA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145025%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `graphics.h` is a deprecated header file for graphics. It is used for old age compilers like Turbo-C++.
In my knowledge, `graphics.h` does not support scan line algorithm, better use some better graphics libraries like [OpenGL](http://opengl.org).
Good luck. :)